# What advantages does a neuron with multiple dendrites have?

Tags: neurophysiology

What advantages does a neuron with multiple dendrites have, as opposed to one with fewer dendrites?

Comment: In terms of computational power?

Comment: more than one dendrite helps to take in more than one information and helps your body process information faster

Answer (score 6):

More dendritic input makes a neuron more suitable as an **integrator**. The more dendrites a neuron has, however, the less faithful it will transmit a single incoming signal, as other incoming input may interfere with transmission. Hence, a neuron with a single dendrite will be better suited to faithfully **relay** incoming signals.

Among the most faithful neurons are the **cone [bipolar cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_bipolar_cell)** in  the central part of the retina, who receive a single input and transmit a single output [(Purves *et al*., 2001)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10850/) via a single axon to the retinal ganglion cell who's axons make up the optic nerve, while on the other end of the spectrum there are, *e.g.*, the **[Purkinje cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purkinje_cell)** in the cerebellum that can receive input from as many as 80,000 fibers [(Konnerth *et. al*, 1998)](http://www.pnas.org/content/87/7/2662.full.pdf).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Konnerth *et. al*, *PNAS* (1998); **87**: 2662-5](http://www.pnas.org/content/87/7/2662.full.pdf)

**-** [Purves *et al*. (eds.), editors. *Neuroscience*. 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. Sunderland (MA): Sinauer Associates (2001) Functional Specialization of the Rod and Cone Systems](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10850/)</sub>

Comment: I thought lateral inhibition was due to inhibitory input to the bipolar cells, making them not perfectly faithful. I was always taught that the spherical bushy cell in the auditory system was the most faithful, but then again, I am an auditory person taught by auditory people.

Comment: @StrongBad - I don't claim bipolars are *the* most faithful - I say 'among the most faithful...' so I guess I'm on the side side of things.